# how to create overlay icons on folders like dropboxx or like google drive in windows platform

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, .net, electron

Actually I want to create **overlayIcons** on my folders/files in **Windows platform** like Green check mark that are similar to dropboxx or google drive.
Currently, We are using Electron.js in my project. Can we use Electron.js for creating overlLay icons?
If not, what is the** technology** to be used to [overlay Icons on Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVFyn.jpg) on Files/folders?
please refer me the path or solution to this problem.

I tried with the electron js and node js to create overlay icons, but I didnot get any solution from them.
I am expecting a solution or path for creating overlay icons on folders.
i.e technology behind the overlay icons in Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way also ones
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects
In this Website he explained step by step I think it may help you

Otherwise
If you can using Electron.js Then you can install this package [electron-overlay-window] and you can Modify the your Js code and C#
code according to this

Comment: Can you suggest any online course for learning the ShelloverlayIconIdentifer

Comment: As much of I know and I explored there is no any course related to this Shell-objects but If you want to know more about how to Implement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843506/shell-icon-overlay-c It is the link you can find you answer definitely

Comment: @ManisaiKumar is using Electron so the provided link will not help since it is a C++ tutorial.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).